# Import Error: Cannot find module 'graphql' from 'apollo-link-state/lib/bundle.umd.js

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo

I am trying to setup React/Apollo frontend with graphql backend(elixir/phoenix). I did `npm install apollo-boost react-apollo graphql --save` and then tried to `import ApolloClient from "apollo-boost";` in my index.js but I am getting

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'graphql' from 'apollo-link-state/lib/bundle.umd.js'
    at require (app.js:61)
    at expanded (app.js:34)
    at app.js:148
    at connectionRemoveConfig.test (bundle.umd.js:6)
    at bundle.umd.js:9
    at bundle.umd.js:151
    at initModule (app.js:42)
    at require (app.js:59)
    at expanded (app.js:34)
    at app.js:148
```

in my browser console. I couldn't find any related question. Can you point what went wrong?
Here is my `package.json`.

```
{
  "repository": {},
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "deploy": "brunch build --production",
    "watch": "brunch watch --stdin"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "apollo-boost": "^0.1.16",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "graphql": "^14.0.2",
    "phoenix": "file:../deps/phoenix",
    "phoenix_html": "file:../deps/phoenix_html",
    "react": "^16.5.1",
    "react-apollo": "^2.1.11",
    "react-dom": "^16.5.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-brunch": "6.1.1",
    "brunch": "2.10.9",
    "clean-css-brunch": "2.10.0",
    "uglify-js-brunch": "2.10.0"
  }
}
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved it by installing them separately.`npm install apollo-client apollo-cache-inmemory apollo-link-http react-apollo graphql-tag graphql --save`

Comment: This works for me: npm i graphql